# Confine dimension of an existing memmap (NumPy)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-memmap

I have a .dat file containing a large (600000,6,8000) float array generated with numpy.memmap.

The third axis represents a date range. At runtime, the user specifies a narrower date range.  The result is that I end up slicing along the 3rd dimension `array[i, :, user_start:user_end]` millions of times during execution.

I know it's possible to offset the memmap by a fixed number, but is there a way to confine the dimensions of the array at the beginning of the run such that I don't need to slice the third axis each time?

Answer (score 2):

A slice of a memory mapped array creates another memory mapped array with the same underlying file, so you could create a new array that is the slice defined by the user input, and use the new array from then on.

If `a` is the memory mapped array, define

```
b = a[:, :, user_start:user_end]
```

and then use `b` instead of repeatedly making the same slice of `a`.  That is, instead of `a[i, :, user_start:user_end]`, use `b[i, :, :]` (or `b[i, :]` or even just `b[i]`, since the final `:` in a numpy index is optional).

Comment: This works syntactically, but seems to have caused a memory leak.